why data is not being retrieved from firestore
const HandleReadData = async () => {
    let url = "123@gmail.com"
    const q = query(collection(db, url));
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q)
    let todosArray = []
    querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        let todo = doc.data().inputData
        console.log("todo is " + todo)
        todosArray.push({ todo })
    })

there is no any result by this method, i have tried to retrieve all the documents that is stored in a collection (named 123@gmail.com), and storing each document in todosArray. Data is not being fetched from the collection. Data is pushed only but not retrieve.

Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot. Besides that, did you try to log the error?

"there is no any result by this method" is not easy to help with. Can you edit your question to show the problem, like for example with a console.log and its output.
